# I'am getting a Segmentation fault while using fgetc(). How can I fix it?

Tags: c, char, segmentation-fault, fgetc

I want to read from a filestream for z bytes. Then I want to give the value in a char array back. I would appreciate it if you could give me an explaination. That's my code since now:

```
char * getData(FILE * fp, long * x)
{
  int z = 0;
  char * data = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFLENGTH);
  strcpy(data,"");

  while(z < BUFFLENGTH-2)
  {
    if(feof(fp) == 0)
    {
      data[z] = fgetc(fp);
      z++;
      x++;
    }
    else
    {
       strcat(data,"\0");
       return data;
    }
  }    
}
```

I know that the segmentation fault is triggered threw this line:

```
data[z] = fgetc(fp);
```

But I dont know why.

Comment: Make sure the index is in range and `fp` is not `NULL`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: `strcat(data,"\0");` is intended to append zero bytes, but will cause *undefined behavior* because what is not a pointer to null-terminated string may be passed as the first argument.

Comment: Do you *really know* the line triggering segmentation fault, using debugger or something? You didn't post your imagination, did you?

Comment: @MikeCAT ... but still depends on the contents of `data[]` ... BTW: `count` is loop invariant and `*x` is never referenced.

Comment: @MikeCAT I check this in an other function. Its not NULL. I thought '\0' is one byte large? That's why you have to make a char array one char larger as you need, or am I wrong?

Comment: `"\0"` is two-byte large because it contains `'\0'` that is written as escape sequence and `'\0'` that is automatically added. And it means to append zero bytes because `'\0'` means termination of string and it comes as the first bytes. Use `data[z] = '\0';` to terminate the string,

Comment: @wildplasser my bad. Ofc it should be z < BUFFLENGTH-2

Comment: Other note: `count` is not updated in the loop, so `while(count < BUFFLENGTH-2)` means `while(1)` if `BUFFLENGTH` is a constant value larger than 2.

Comment: You need to check if `fgetc` returns `EOF`

Comment: @MikeCAT yes wildplasser already said it. Edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should check if the allocation was successful.
- You should check if the reading was successful *after* calling `fgetc()` instead of using `feof()`.
- This usage of `strcat()` will invoke *undefined behavior* if one or more bytes are read from the file and no byte its value is zero is read because a pointer pointing something which is not null-terminated string will be passed to `strcat()` and it will access area allocated via `malloc()` and not initialized. Instead of this, you should terminate the string by adding `'\0'`.
- You should return something explicitly even if the length read exceeds the limit, otherwise you will invoke *undefined behavior* if the caller use the return value.

code with these advices applied:

```
char * getData(FILE * fp, long * x)
{
  int z = 0;
  char * data = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFLENGTH);
  if(data == NULL) return NULL;
  /* strcpy() isn't needed because it will be overwritten */

  while(z < BUFFLENGTH-2)
  {
    int input = fgetc(fp);
    if(input != EOF)
    {
      data[z] = input;
      z++;
      x++;
    }
    else
    {
       data[z] = '\0';
       return data;
    }
  }
  free(data);
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I tried to access it with: char * new = getData(fp, &byteatm);  printf("%s", new); but it always says (null). If you free(data) after the while loop isnt it destroyed in memory?

Comment: `free()` will destroy the (validity of) contents in memory. Make the file size below the limit or change the process for files that are too large.

Comment: It's just one file with 1042 Bytes. How can such a small file be too large?

Comment: It depends on the value of `BUFFLENGTH`. For example, if its value is `80`, any file that is 78 bytes or larger are too large.

Comment: But if EOF  is reached it returns data and leaves the function, or?

Comment: [Coudl't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KSMhakVHzfQOMkGs) that `NULL` is returned.

Comment: If I use your tool. I cant neither. Even if I add my whole file (file I want to open). But if I say FILE * fp = fopen(myfile,"r"); It always return NULL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105498/discussion-between-missjohanna-and-mikecat).

Comment: Couldn't reproduce in neither my local environment (WIndows 7 x64, GCC 4.8.1) nor [online](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FKNJMRR6wgSNTVwE).

Comment: I think I found the mistake. If z< BUFFLENGTH and EOF is not reached it gave simply NULL back. But if I add a return data; after the while loop its working.